# Jquery slide Timer

Tags: jquery, timer

I'm looking a plugin of jquery for a bar with a countdown. I attach an image of example.

Thanks for your help guys.

[Example http://www.rodboc.com/archivos/000-ddU5IYzzTL.png](http://www.rodboc.com/archivos/000-ddU5IYzzTL.png)

Comment: have you done some googling on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a countdown plugin for jquery: http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html
It is quite powerful so reading it's documentation (doing some research **yourself**) should help you figure out how to make it look like you would like it to.